# Find the Radius of Convergence of a Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the function $f(z)$ defined by the series $$f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nz}\cos (nz).$$

I am asked to find the domain of $f$ defined by the convergence of the series.

To find the radius of the convergence, we need to firstly transform the summand into the form of power series.

So I simply wrote down the formula as:
\begin{align*}
e^{-nz}\cos(nz)&=\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-nz)^{k}}{k!}\Big)\Big(\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{\ell}}{(2\ell)!}(nz)^{2\ell}\Big)\\
&=\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k}n^{k}}{k!}z^{k}\Big)\Big(\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{\ell}n^{2\ell}}{(2\ell)!}z^{2\ell}\Big)\\
&:=\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}z^{k}\Big)\Big(\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}b_{\ell}z^{2\ell}\Big)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{\substack{k+2\ell=m \\ k,\ell\geq 0}}a_{k}b_{\ell}\Big)z^{m}.
\end{align*}

But then I don't know how to proceed, as then if I sum over $n$, the coefficients are still not clear enough to calculate the radius of convergence.

Did I head to a wrong direction?

Since this question is related to complex analysis and power series, after searching around the forum, I am still not sure if I've asked a duplicated question. If so, please point it out and I will close the question.

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Given the discussions under my post and two answers, here is some editions here.

(1) I am sorry for forgetting to mention that $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Thus, it seems not sufficient to argue only for $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

(2) This problem has a follow-up part (b) asking me to argue if $f(z)$ can be extended analytically to a larger domain. If so, I need to find the maximal domain of the extension and classify its singularities. Therefore, I think we need to find a power series expansion of $f(z)$ and then "return" it to a function, just like what *Viktor Glombik* suggested.

I am currently trying to show what *Viktor Glombik* could not prove, and I would post my proof here if I came up one.

Thank all of you so much for your discussion and answers!

**Edit 2:**

**Following the idea of Viktor Glombik, I think I prove the whole problem now. In this edition, I will first post the whole problem and then post my proof. The proof greatly follows Viktor Glombik.**

> Consider the function $f(z)$ defined by the series $$f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nz}\cos(nz).$$
> (1) Find the domain of $f$ defined by the convergence of the series.
>
> (2) Can $f$ be extended analytically to a larger domain? If so, find the maximal domain of the extension and classify its singularities.

*Proof (1):*

Note that $$\cos (nz)=\dfrac{e^{inz}+e^{-inz}}{2},$$ so that we have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nz}\cos(nz)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{(i-1)nz}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-(i+1)nz}.$$

Both sums are geometric sum with $$r_{1}=e^{(i-1)z},\ r_{2}=e^{-(i+1)z},$$ which converges if and only if $$|r_{1}|<1,\ \text{and}\ |r_{2}|<1.$$

Write $z:=x+iy$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then we have $$|r_{1}|=\Big|e^{i(x-y)}e^{-y-x}\Big|=\Big|e^{-(y+x)}\Big|=e^{-(y+x)},$$ and $$|r_{2}|=\Big|e^{i(-x-y)}e^{y-x}\Big|=\Big|e^{y-x}\Big|=e^{y-x}.$$

Then, we have $$|r_{1}|<1\implies e^{y+x}>1\implies y+x>0\implies y>-x,$$ $$|r_{2}|<1\implies e^{y-x}<1\implies y-x<0\implies y<x.$$

Thus, the domain of the convergence is the set $$\mathcal{A}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:-\Re(z)<\Im(z)<\Re(z)\}.$$

*Proof (2):*

Now, define the partial sums $$S_{1,k}:=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{k}r_{1}^{n},\ S_{2,k}:=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{k}r_{2}^{n}.$$

Then, by the summation formula of geometric series, we have $$S_{1,k}=\dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{1-r_{1}^{k+1}}{1-r_{1}},\ S_{2,k}=\dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{1-r_{2}^{k+1}}{1-r_{2}}.$$

Now, for all $z\in\mathcal{A}$, taking $k\rightarrow\infty$ yields us $$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(\dfrac{1}{1-e^{(i-1)z}}\Big)+\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(\dfrac{1}{1-e^{-(i+1)z}}\Big).$$

It is then clear that the singularities are those $z\in\mathbb{C}$ that make
\begin{align*}
&e^{(i-1)z}=1,\ \text{or}\ e^{-(i+1)z}=1 \\
\iff &(i-1)z=2k\pi i,\ \text{or}\ (i+1)z=-2k\pi i,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}.\\
\iff &z=(1-i)k\pi,\ \text{or}\ z=-(1+i)k\pi,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\Big(\{z=(1-i)k\pi,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{z=-(1+i)k\pi,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\Big),$ $$f(z):=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(\dfrac{1}{1-e^{(i-1)z}}\Big)+\dfrac{1}{2}\Big(\dfrac{1}{1-e^{-(i+1)z}}\Big)$$ is an analytic continuation of $f(z)$.

**I think I did not understand the point of this question before because I thought it was asking me to give the radius of the convergence, but it was actually asking me to simply give a domain.**

**Also, the idea of using geometric series is brilliant, credit to Viktor.**

Comment: I would suggest writing the $\cos(nz)$ term in its exponential form.

Comment: @Clayton you mean $\cos(nz)=\dfrac{e^{inz}+e^{-inz}}{2}$?

Comment: $z > 0$ implies converges absolutely, $z \le 0$ implies terms don't even go to $0$.

Comment: @mathworker21 how did you get this conclusion?

Comment: It certainly converges for $Re(z) > 0$.

Comment: I maintain my correctness.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am still confused about how you concluded the convergence. Would you mind explaining it a little bit?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical $|\cos(nz)| \le 1$, $\sum_n e^{-nz} < \infty$ for $z > 0$

Comment: The use of the letter $z$ suggests that $z$ is a complex number, so all this talk of $z>0$ and $z<0$ is obviously applicable only to *real* values of $z$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't get why you said "so". It's always true that talking about $z > 0$ and $z < 0$ is only applicable to real $z$, regardless of the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you asked how to find the series expansion of your function:
Since $\cos(nz) = \frac{e^{i n z} + e^{-i n z}}{2}$, we have
$$
\cos(nz) e^{-nz}
= \frac{e^{-(i + 1)nz} + e^{(i - 1)nz}}{2}.
$$
Now, we can just use those series definitions to get
\begin{align}
\cos(nz) e^{-nz}
& = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-(i + 1)n z)^k}{k!}
+ \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{((i - 1)n z)^k}{k!}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(nz)^k}{k!} \left((-(i + 1))^k + ((i - 1))^k\right)\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(nz)^k}{k!} 2^{\frac{k}{2} + 1} \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi k}{4}\right)\right) \\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}nz\right)^k}{k!} \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi k}{4}\right).
\end{align}
Now we know that $\cos\left(\frac{3 \pi k}{4}\right) \in \left\{ 0, \pm 1, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

When summing over all $n$, we can split the sum use the properties of the geometric sum and obtain (for $e^{\Re(z) \pm \Im(z)} > 1$)
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \cos(nz) e^{-nz}
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(i + 1)nz} + e^{(i - 1)nz}}{2}
= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{e^{(1 + i) z}}{e^{(1 + i) z} - 1}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^z}{e^{i z} -e^z}\\
& = \frac{e^z (e^{2 i z} - 2 e^{(1 + i) z} + 1)}{2 (e^{i z} - e^{z}) (e^{(1 + i) z} - 1)}
= \frac{1}{2 (e^{(1 + i) z} - 1)} + \frac{e^{i z}}{2 (e^z - e^{i z})} + 1.
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is pretty inspiring, as at least I know how to deal with such a summand (for a less complicated problem) in the future. No worry about the typos!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Thank you but remember that the other answer actually addresses the primary question of the radius of convergence.

Comment: I just see your edition, sorry for the late reply. It is really brilliant to use the geometric sum. I will combine your answer and Mark's answer. However, it seems that Mark assumed $z\in\mathbb{R}$ in his argument of $z>0$.

Answer (score 1):

When $z > 0$ and $n \in \Bbb N$, 
$$
\left| e^{-nz} \cos(nz)\right| \leq \left| e^{-nz} \right| 
$$
so the series converges absolutely, and in fact
$$
\left| \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} e^{-nz} \cos(nz)\right| \leq \left| \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} e^{-nz} \right| = \frac1{1-e^{-z}}
$$

When $z=0$,
$$\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} e^{-nz} = \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} 1$$
which clearly diverges.

So the question is whether the series converges for any $z<0$.

Clearly it does not converge absolutely for any $z < 0$ if $z$ is not a multiple of $\pi$ because then there is an infinite set of $n$ values for which the fractional part of $nz/2\pi$ obeys
$$\left\{\frac{nz}{2\pi}\right\} > \frac16$$  and each such value contributes at least 
$\frac12(e^{-z})^n$ to the sum, so the sum of the absolute values of the terms is greater than that of a geometric series with increasing terms, which diverges.

Also the series does not converge absolutely for any $z = -k\pi$ with $k \in \Bbb Z^+$: For even $k$, this becomes simply the sum of $e^{-nz}$ while for odd $k$ you can pair each even term with its successor to get $(1-e^{k\pi}) \sum e^{2kn\pi}$ which again is the sum of a geometric series with increasing terms.

So the domain of *absolute* convergence is simply $z>0$.  That answers the question that whoever posed this probably meant to be asking, since people generally don't talk about a radius or domain of conditional convergence.

We are left with the question of whether for any $z <0$ the series can converge conditionally; and I would modify the question to ask whether there is any $z \in \Bbb C$ with $\Re (z) < 0$ such that $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} e^{-nz} \cos(nz)$ converges conditionally.

I believe it is a theorem that if $S_n$ is a series whose positive terms taken by themselves diverge, and whose negative terms summed by themselves converge, then the terms of $S_n$ can be rearranged and grouped such that the sums of the groups form a convergent series.  The argument above about absolute convergence can be applied to both the positive and negative terms.  Therefore, when $z <0$ but $z$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$, the series converges conditionally (but not absolutely).

---

**EDIT After Clayton's comment**

A further requirement in the statement about conditional convergence is "and both the positive terms and the negative terms go to zero as $n\to\infty$.  This sequence does not meet that requirement, so the rearrangement theorem cannot be used to prove it is conditionally convergent.

It is still plausible that for some values of $z$ with $\Re(z) < 0$ the terms can be rearranged (regrouped) to show conditional convergence but it seems unlikely since the absolute value of the typical term grows exponentially.

Comment: @mathworker21 I think he mentioned about $z=0$ after the argument for $z>0$.

Comment: Mark, not sure if you misremembered or mistyped: the theorem you are thinking of is Riemann’s Rearrangement Theorem. Both positive terms by themselves and negative terms by themselves must form divergent series, and we also need the terms to go to $0$. Without this latter part, the statement isn’t true.

Comment: I agreed with your argument for the radius of convergence. But it seems that you assumed $z\in\mathbb{R}$ in your argument (at least for $z=0$ and $z>0$).

Comment: @Clayton You are absolutely right.  I blew it on that statement. I am correcting the answer.